# Flutter: save a generated PDF from preview page with a custom function

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-generation, dart-pub

I'm using the `pdf` package (link to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) page) to create documents inside my app.

How can I save the document from the preview page?
I know about the built-in `print`  and `share` functions, but I need something else.

I need a function that does the following:

1. save the document to the device
2. upload it to Firebase Storage
3. delete the local file

I know how to do all of these steps, but I'm unable to access the `Uint8List`  bytes of the pdf document that is being previewed... I've tried to add a `PdfPreviewAction`, but I still can't access the bytes of the document from it

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is call the save method in the Document() object

```
import "package:pdf/widgets.dart" as w;
final pdf = w.Document();
Future<Uint8List> getPDFData() async {
return await pdf.save();
}
```

you can do all the operations using the getPDFData() method
for example:

```
return PdfPreview(
        build: (format) => getPdfData(),
        actions: [
          PdfPreviewAction(
              icon: Icon(Icons.print),
              onPressed: (context, fn, format) {
                //if you call fn(format), you'll get Future<UInt8List>
              }),
              
        ],
      );
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'd like to call this function from a `PdfPreviewAction`, which is the third icon button in the bottom bar. Is that possible?

Comment: what is PdfPreviewAction? is it your own class?. this library doesn't has a class named PdfPreviewAction in my knowledge.

Comment: It's part of the `printing` package. Here's the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/printing/latest/printing/PdfPreview-class.html) for it

Comment: try this,  PdfPreviewAction(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                  onPressed: (context, fn, format) {
                    print(fn(format));
                  })

Comment: I'll try and let you know... Thanks